# 1980s Superman comic where he fights a blonde mutant

Tags: dc, superman, episode-identification

I was hoping you could help me identify a Superman comic I read.

The main thrust of the comic is that Superman battles a blonde, mutated man who grows bigger and larger.

- A scientist is involved who makes the villain stronger
- It was from the 80s.

Does anyone know which comic this is?

Ok this is the cover I found and wanted to know which comic and story it was

[image: Cover art]

Comment: any other details you can remember?

Comment: you sure you're not thinking of Nuclear Man from Superman IV?

Comment: The DC Comics database has nearly 2000 listings for heroes & villains with blond hair. Something tells me we'll need to narrow this down somewhat. Was the "mutated man" wearing a costume? If so, what did it look like? What do you mean by "mutated"? Did he look human except for hulking out? What caused him to hulk out? Were any other heroes or villains present in the comic?

Comment: Without more information to go on, the only thing I've found that fits is Pulsar - a blond man given powers by his scientist dad. He was a one-off Superboy villain from 1982.

Comment: Just to nit-pick....blonde or blond? I thought one is female and one is male.

Answer (score 6):

That cover made all the difference. This is Superman Special #10, which is a comic published only in Germany during the latter 1970's. You probably had the reprint from 1985.

The villain depicted on the cover - your mutated blond man - is Benny Baker, a sports writer who received Hulk-like powers from a scientist's formula. Benny took the name "The Fist" and planned on using his new abilities to become the new World's Heavyweight Champion.

The formula given to Benny is a type of "irradiated adrenaline". Therefore, the more his adrenaline pumps, the stronger he gets... eventually reaching a point where he is stronger than even Superman. When fighting in front of a crowd, the roaring & applause of the crowd further gets Benny's adrenaline going, making him even stronger. Superman eventually figures this out and uses it to his advantage.

Comment: How does he use it to his advantage?

Comment: @Richard - I don't have access to the actual comic, but the summary page I was reading said that once he figured that part out, he was able to de-power the guy. Maybe he moved the fight elsewhere with no audience? Not sure.

Comment: What does he cover looks like for the Superman Special Comic #10 that was the original one released in Germay in 1976?